# Bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $[0,\alpha]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory, ordinals

Suppose $\alpha<\omega_1$ is an ordinal. Can anyone give me an example of a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $[0,\alpha]:=\{\gamma: \gamma\leq \alpha\}$. Is there an order preserving bijection between the two sets?

Comment: I think there is a definitinal issue going on here, as i defined $\omega_1$ as the smallest ordinal that is not countable. That said, what is your definition?

Comment: @JayTuma Same definition. So $\alpha$ is a countable ordinal, therefore the set  $[0,\alpha]$ is countable.

Comment: nice, then since isomorphic ordinal are equal, it follows that $\mathbb{N} = \omega$ admits an order preserving bijection (isomorphism) with $\alpha$ if and only if $\alpha = \omega$. But $[0, \alpha] = \alpha + 1$ and $\omega$ is limit, so the answer to the second question is never.

For the first one i think is quite not clear... you only know this map exists (i.e. $\alpha$ itself is defined somehow through this map).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bijection iff $\omega\le\alpha<\omega_1$. There is no order-preserving bijection for any $\alpha$, since $[0,\alpha]$ has a largest element, and $\Bbb N$ does not. Actually producing a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $[0,\alpha]$ will depend on the specific $\alpha$. For instance, one bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $[0,\omega+\omega]$ sends $0$ to $\omega+\omega$, $2n$ to $n$ if $n>0$, and $2n+1$ to $\omega+n$:

$$f:\Bbb N\to\omega+\omega:n\mapsto\begin{cases}
\omega+\omega,&\text{if }n=0\\
k,&\text{if }n=2k>0\\
\omega+k,&\text{if }n=2k+1\;.
\end{cases}$$